# Python Psycopg error and connection handling (v MySQLdb)

Tags: python, mysql, psycopg2

Is there a way to make psycopg and postgres deal with errors without having to reestablish the connection, like MySQLdb?  The commented version of the below works with MySQLdb, the comments make it work with Psycopg2:

```
results = {'felicitas': 3, 'volumes': 8, 'acillevs': 1, 'mosaics': 13, 'perat\xe9': 1, 'representative': 6....}
for item in sorted(results):
    try:
        cur.execute("""insert into resultstab values ('%s', %d)""" % (item, results[item]))
        print item, results[item]
#       conn.commit()
    except:
#       conn=psycopg2.connect(user='bvm', database='wdb', password='redacted')
#       cur=conn.cursor()
        print 'choked on', item
        continue
```

This must slow things down, could anyone give a suggestion for passing over formatting errors?  Obviously the above chokes on apostrophes, but is there a way to make it pass over that without getting something like the following, or committing, reconnecting, etc?:

```
agreement 19
agreements 1
agrees 1
agrippa 9
choked on agrippa's
choked on agrippina
```

Comment: can you add the code of addthings? becaue I guess that you have a quoting problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should let psycopg do the escaping for you by passing to the execute() method the parameters instead of doing the formatting yourself with '%'. That is:

```
cur.execute("insert into resultstab values (%s, %s)", (item, results[item]))
```

Note how we use "%s" as a marker even for non-string values and avoid quotes in the query. psycopg will do all the quoting for us.

Then, if you want to ignore some errors, just rollback and continue.

```
try:
    cur.execute("SELECT this is an error")
except:
    conn.rollback()
```

That's all. psycopg will rollback and start a new transaction on your next statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code looks like this at the moment:

```
l = "a very long ... text".split()
for e in l:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO yourtable (yourcol) VALUES ('" + e + "')")
```

So try to change it into something like this:

```
l = "a very long ... text".split()
for e in l:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO yourtable (yourcol) VALUES (%s)", (e,))
```

so never forget to pass your parameters in the parameters list, then you don't have to care about your quotes and stuff, it is also more secure. You can read more about it at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

also have a look there at the method .executemany() which is specially designed to execute the same statement multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, I do do the string assignment as you suggest.  I think my bigger problem is that when I try to add something invalid, I lose the connection, and have to reestablish it, I am curious if there is a way to make it more like mysqldb, where errors can just be skipped w/ normal exception handling